# Yajra data table using search and custom filter together

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

```
Laravel: 5.6.39

PHP: 7.2.10

Yajra Table: 8.0
```

**Sample code**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        var url = "{{ url('/admin/posts') }}";
        $(function() {
            var oTable = $('#admin-posts').DataTable({
                dom: "<'row'<'col-xs-12'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'p>>r>"+
            "<'row'<'col-xs-12't>>"+
            "<'row'<'col-xs-12'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>>",
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: url,
                    data: function (d) {
                        d.category = $("#category option:selected").val();
                        d.language = $("#language option:selected").val();
                    }
                },            
                columns: [
                    { data: 'post_checkbox', name: 'post_checkbox' },
                    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                    { data: 'post_label', name: 'post_label' },
                    { data: 'post_link', name: 'post_link' },
                    { data: 'view', name: 'view' },
                    { data: 'post_category', name: 'post_category' },
                ],
                stateSave: true,
                bDestroy: true,
          });

          $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
               oTable.draw();
               e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
   });
```

Now if I will remove `dom` search and filter both can be seen but search will still not work, if I will remove the filters then only search is working, I believe there should be some customization to dom or something, that will allow both search and filters.

In [documentation](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/collection/custom-filter) too, there is no search.

There is one [option](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/regex) to enable search like below code, but it does **not** seems to be working, also for that I have removed dom attribute in above code.

```
search: {
        "regex": true
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how the search works automatically, but I have coded for my requirement and that is working fine and give some idea, how you can do it.

You can get search term using `$request->get('search')['value']` and now write code to check if your condition is getting satisfied and filter the results in your controller or Model. Below is the code  to do it in Controller.

```
return DataTables::eloquent($posts)
        ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->has('category') && ! is_null($request->get('category'))) {
                $query->where('post_category', $request->get('category'));
            }

            if ($request->has('language') && ! is_null($request->get('language')) ) {
                $query->where('post_language', $request->get('language'));
            }
            
            if ($request->has('search') && ! is_null($request->get('search')['value']) ) {
                $regex = $request->get('search')['value'];
                return $query->where('your_field', 'like', '%' . $regex . '%');
                });
            }
        })->toJson();
```

Comment: Hi, I had the same code (as example) but my $request->get('category') is always empty.

Comment: @Swim89 Can you show me your JS, so that I can get a better idea of that?

Comment: @Swim89 Can you show me `#states` and `#federations` html?

Comment: @Swim89 I guess, it is select box, so you can use ` d.state = $('#states :selected').val();
                        d.federation = $('#federations :selected').val();` instead of ` d.state = $('#states').val();
                        d.federation = $('#federations').val();`

Comment: i'm geting error that `Method where does not exist.` How to resolve it?

Comment: @Rakhi I would like to suggest you to post a new question.