# Laravel DataTables Yajrabox Not Displaying Data

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-artisan, yajra-datatable

I am facing this problem from last few days and cannot find any solution for this. 
I am using [YajraTables](http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation) , and as output JSON result i am getting "c" at starting of every json it renders.

I am also getting same error when i use php artisan command

PHP Version: **7.2.11**
Laravel Version: **5.7.19**

### **Here are some screens of error:**

**Error on Command Line using Artisan**
[image]

**Error on HTML Screen**
[image]

**JSON Error:**
[image]

**Raw JSON which shows "c" in starting of every JSON response of Yajra Tables**
[image]

Here is how i included YajraTables
[image]

**Controller Code:**

```
public function users(){

    $accounts = Accounts::select(['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'address', 'city'])->get();

    return Datatables::of($accounts)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($accounts) {
            return '<a href="bills/'.$accounts->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View Bills</a><a href="edit_accounts/'.$accounts->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn delete_account btn-sm btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="'.$accounts->id.'"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>';
        })
        ->editColumn('id', 'ID: {{$id}}')
        ->make(true);

}
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('users') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'mobile', name: 'mobile' },
            { data: 'address', name: 'address' },
            { data: 'city', name: 'city' },
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ]
    });
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">

                    <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>

                    </thead>

                </table>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
public function users(){

    $accounts = Accounts::select(['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'address', 'city']);

     return DataTables::eloquent($accounts)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($account) {
            return '<a href="bills/'.$account->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View Bills</a><a href="edit_accounts/'.$account->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn delete_account btn-sm btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="'.$account->id.'"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>';
        })
        ->editColumn('id', 'ID: {{$id}}')
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->toJson();

}
```

and let me know, if you are getting any error now. Do not forget to specify raw column, when you are adding html.

it seems you have added unnecessary character in some place, but I would like you to test with

```
->addColumn('action','<a href="bills/'.$accounts->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View Bills</a><a href="edit_accounts/'.$accounts->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn delete_account btn-sm btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="'.$accounts->id.'"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>';
        );
```

check it it works, if you will ask me, I will put this in a blade/partial and use as

```
 ->addColumn('action', function(Video $account){
       return view('tagging.video-checkbox', compact('account'))->render();
 });
```

Comment: I've Discovered that error was in public/index.php , here is screenshot to that: https://i.imgur.com/jlmTK2G.png  and also see output: https://i.imgur.com/SlnKDdL.png

Comment: @SahilPasricha but still you need to specify rawColumns, are you still getting any error?

Comment: @SahilPasricha Can you tell me, which version laravel and yajra table you are using?

Comment: @SahilPasricha You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978555/yajra-data-table-using-search-and-custom-filter-together/55063096#55063096), It is static method in at least yajra table 8.0, I am using. Also you can also use your ` Datatables::of(` , I have not used because I have not tried that.

Comment: @SahilPasricha notice my answer, there is no `get()` in screenshot, I can see you are using `get()`.

Comment: I have not used get() , but used your given code only. It doesn't work

Comment: @SahilPasricha In your screenshot, it looks `$accounts = Accounts::select(['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'address', 'city'])->get();` where as I have posted `$accounts = Accounts::select(['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'address', 'city']);`.

Comment: Here is my code  `$accounts = Accounts::select(['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'address', 'city']);` , i removed get

Comment: @SahilPasricha make it `rawColumns(['action','])` and let me know.

Comment: It still prints "c" at the starting of JSON

Comment: @SahilPasricha Can you temporarily make the action button/link just a string or just static link and test it and let me know if you are still getting the same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189809/discussion-between-sahil-pasricha-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**
Look for this file in your project

```
vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js
```

The copy it and put it in your assets public folder and then make sure you include it as a scribe before

```
{{ $dataTable->scripts() }}
```

so, it should be like this

```
<script src="{{ url('/') }}/assets/js/buttons.server-side.js"></script>
{{ $dataTable->scripts() }}
```

and hopefully it will be fixed.

**SOLUTION 2**
Remove buttons.
On your build method in the datatable class, remove buttons by adding something like this

```
 ->parameters([
        'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
        'buttons' => [],
    ]);
```

So, the final thing should look like this

```
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->setTableId('users-table')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->dom('Bfrtip')
                ->orderBy(1)
                -->parameters([
                    'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
                    'buttons' => [],
                ]);
}
```

**CONCLUSION**
If you still get an error, go to inspect and see if there is any warning.
All the best!